# How can I solve the following inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, absolute-value

I have the inequality:

$lg((x^3-x-1)^2) < 2 lg(x^3+x-1)$

And I'm not sure how should I go about solving it. I wrote it like this:

$2lg(x^3-x-1) < 2lg(x^3+x-1)$

$lg(x^3-x-1) < lg(x^3 + x - 1)$       (*)

Here I have the conditions:

$x^3-x-1 > 0$

$x^3+x-1 > 0$

At first this stumped me, but then I realised I can just add the inequalities to get:

$2x^3 -2> 0$

$x^3-1>0$

$x^3>1 \Rightarrow x \in (1, + \infty)$

So that is our condition.

Going back to (*) and raising the inequality to the power of $10$, I got:

$x^3-x-1 < x^3+ x - 1$

$2x>0 \Rightarrow x \in(0, +\infty)$

So, if we also consider the condition, we have

$x \in (1, + \infty) \cap (0, + \infty)$

So $x \in (1, + \infty)$.

The problem with this answer is that it is wrong. My textbook lists the following possible answers:

**A.** $\mathbb{R}$

**B.** $(0, + \infty)$

**C.** $(1, + \infty)$

**D.** $(0, 1)$

**E.** Other answer

So I got answer **C**, but after I checked the back of the book I found that the correct answer should be **E**. So, what did I do wrong and what is that other answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain it's $$x^3-x-1\neq0$$ and $$x^3+x-1>0.$$ 
Now, since $$\ln(x^3-x-1)^2=2\ln|x^3-x-1|,$$ we need to solve
$$|x^3-x-1|<x^3+x-1$$ or
$$-x^3-x+1<x^3-x-1<x^3+x-1.$$
The left inequality gives $x>1$ and the right inequality gives $x>0,$ which gives the answer:
$$(1,+\infty)\setminus\{x|x^3-x-1=0\}.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but it looks like I do not understand. Can you please provide a little more detail as to how did you get to your third line? I understand that by the logarithm properties you can move the exponent $2$ in front of the logarithm, but why did you have to change the parentheses to absolute value?

Comment: @Bogdan Vlad Because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and $\log_b{a^2}=2\log_b\sqrt{a^2}=2\log_b|a|.$

Answer (score 1):

Your condition isn't quite right.  When $x = 1.1$, $x^3−x−1 = 1.331 - 1.1 - 1 < 0$.

From $\log(x^3 - x - 1) < \log(x^3 + x - 1)$, subtract one side from the other, then use a logarithm property to get one logarithm.  \begin{align*}
0 &< \log(x^3 + x - 1) - \log(x^3 - x - 1)  \\
0 &< \log \left( \frac{x^3 + x - 1}{x^3 - x - 1} \right)
\end{align*}
Apply $f(y) = 10^y$ to both sides to obtain
\begin{align*}
1 &< \frac{x^3 + x - 1}{x^3 - x - 1}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
which you demonstrated you knew how to handle in your question.  (Don't forget, when you go from $a < \frac{b}{c}$ to $ac < b$ you may have inadvertently multiplied by zero for some values of $x$ that you aren't currently thinking about (yielding $0 < 0$, which is false).  You should check what happens in those cases.  For instance, here, what happens when $x^3 - x - 1 = 0$ in the original equation?)

Comment: So, I need the add the condition of $x^3-x-1 \ne 0$. But is it correct to not apply any conditions for the logarithms? Shouldn't you have applied the condition of $\dfrac{x^3+x+1}{x^3-x-1} > 0$ since you have $0 < log \bigg (\dfrac{x^3+x-1}{x^3-x-1} \bigg )$? Or some other logarithm condition in a previous step? And that is my problem, I don't know how to solve those conditions.

Comment: @BogdanVlad : From "$1 < \frac{x^3+x-1}{x^3-x-1}$", you get "$x^3 -x-1 < x^3 +x-1$ and $x^3 -x-1 \neq 0$", where you have *already* used "$x^3 -x-1 > 0$" (coming from its logarithm) to not reverse the sense of the inequality.  (Recall that when you multiply through an inequality by a negative number it reverses the sense of the inequality.)

Answer (score 0):

Better not get rid of the squares -- they're your friend. So we have $$\log{(x^3-x-1)^2}< \log{(x^3+x-1)^2}.$$ Since the logarithm is monotonic, this implies $$(x^3-x-1)^2< (x^3+x-1)^2,$$ or that $$(x^3-x-1)^2- (x^3+x-1)^2<0.$$ This is easily factored to give $$(x^3-x-1+x^3+x-1)(x^3-x-1-x^3-x+1)<0,$$ or $$(2x^3-2)(-2x)<0,$$ or more simply $$x(x^3-1)=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)>0,$$ which implies $$x(x-1)>0$$ since $x^2+x+1$ is always positive.

I believe you can now take it from here.

---

Well, you also have to factor in that the original inequality makes sense only for $x^3+x-1>0$ and $x^3-x-1\ne 0.$